# R: Grouping data in a plot

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a time series and I have reduced this serie with a transformation. For example

The original time serie:

```
T=(12,13,14,20,65,78,85,35)
```

and transformed one is:

```
T'=(17.22009  27.96722 111.16376  71.33732)
```

and now I want to have such a diagram, in its x-axis I have 8 values but for each 2 values one value from `T'` . I can do sme thing like this in R:
[image]

but in the second Plot I want to extend the the diagram on 8 values too

Comment: Can you please add the commands you use for drawing the plots? Btw `T'` is not a valid variable name in R, since `'` marks the start/end of a string.

Comment: Thank you @AndreSilva, actually I want to do this job with more than 1000 values, and I think this way is not perfect

Comment: @Backlin what I have here wrote is not a R code, it is only an example

Comment: Yes I understood, but wanted Kaja to add it anyway. I might be obnoxious now, but it's common decency (in lack of better words) to provide potential answerers with a [runnable reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to start working from.

Comment: A big problems is that you're just using the index for x-values. If this is really time series data then these values should be matched to times. If those were your x-axis that would be the correct solution, and you might not even have a problem at all. As your question is formulated one can only guess as to how this should really be plotted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `T'` is called `Tc` in R you fix the lower one by

```
plot(0:length(Tc)*2, c(Tc, tail(Tc,1)), type="s")
```

The additional element added by `tail` is needed for drawing the last segment, from 6 to 8.

[image]

**Update**

If you just want to stretch the second plot to go between 1 and 8, you can do

```
plot(seq(1, 2*length(Tc), length.out=length(Tc)+1), c(Tc, tail(Tc,1)), type="s")
```

However, I take it that each value of the second plot corresponds to two values of the upper plot, so perhaps the best way to visualize it then would be

```
barplot(Tc, width=2, space=0)
lines(seq(Tb)-.5, Tb, type="b", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I think it is my answer, but this diagram begins with `0` if I want to begin with `1` what should I do? I have changed `plot(0:length(Tc)*2...` to `plot(1:length(Tc)*2...` but I get an error